# How to configure Colcon?

Tags: ros2, colcon, docker

I have been working for some time on a [ros2 docker container development environment](https://gitlab.com/docker5348/ros2_main_dev_container). Since I had to do some `git clone` commands into an imaginary folder and needed to use an advanced `colcon build` command to get all the packages built correctly, I was wondering how to configure colcon correctly so I can make the process smarter than

```
. /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.sh && colcon build --build-base ros_ws/build --install-base ros_ws/install --base-paths /ros_default /ros_ws /ros_debug_ws /microros_ws
```

Does anyone know how to configure colcon correctly and where to save these configurations?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly related to what you are asking, but I'd look into establishing an alias for the command.

You can define an alias in your `.bashrc` for the `colcon build` section as follows:

```bash
alias custom_colcon_build = colcon build --build-base ros_ws/build --install-base ros_ws/install --base-paths /ros_default /ros_ws /ros_debug_ws /microros_ws
```

If you use it, then your command becomes :

```bash
. /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.sh && custom_colcon_build
```

You can tweak it even further by leaving the `source /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.sh` as one of the last commands to be executed in the `.bashrc`. That way you'll only need to call `custom_colcon_build`.

You can also look into writing your own colcon hook, but I personally would find the alias method less invasive, and more portable in case things change.

Comment: As you can see in the linked [gitlab project](https://gitlab.com/docker5348/ros2_main_dev_container) [Dockerfile](https://gitlab.com/docker5348/ros2_main_dev_container/-/blob/Devel/Dockerfile?ref_type=heads), this is exactly what I've been doing so far.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the dockerfile before. I'll be watching this post in case someone provides a better alternative to it.